# How can I pip install for development?

Tags: python, django, setuptools

I'm trying to `pip install` a GitHub project locally, outside of `site-packages` so that I can modify it, etc.

I've added `-e git+git@github.com:Starcross/django-starcross-gallery.git#egg=gallery` to my `requirements.txt` which brings the relevant part of my project layout to look like this:

```
/home/mat/venv/proj/
└── src
    └── gallery
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── build.sh
        ├── django_starcross_gallery.egg-info
        │   ├── dependency_links.txt
        │   ├── PKG-INFO
        │   ├── requires.txt
        │   ├── SOURCES.txt
        │   └── top_level.txt
        ├── forms.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── MANIFEST.in
        ├── models.py
        ├── README.rst
        ├── settings.py
        ├── setup.py
        ├── signals.py
        ├── static
        │   └── ...
        ├── templates
        │   └── ...
        ├── tests
        │   └── ...
        ├── tests.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── views.py
```

As far as I can see the problem is that these .egg-link and .pth files like one level too deep:

```
lib/python3.6/site-packages/django-starcross-gallery.egg-link:
/home/mat/venv/proj/src/gallery
.

lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth:
/home/mat/venv/proj/src/gallery
```

I can fix everything by either moving `gallery` a level deeper, or changing `django-starcross-gallery.egg-link` and `easy-install.pth` to point to `src`.

**Is there a config parameter I can pass in requirements.txt to make this work properly?** Or do I have to adjust the project layout to fit?

Comment: As far as I can see it, the problem is with the package itself as it doesn't have a valid python project structure and therefore isn't packaged with python tools (instead using a custom build script). If you clone the repo and run `python setup.py egg_info` to generate the package metadata, you'll see that no sources are included (as there are no packages to include to it). As `pip` won't obviously guess and run custom build scripts on installation, I don't see any chance for you to solve it by playing with `pip` options unless the package maintainer changes the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to modify it, why not just clone the repo. To make your interpreter able to find and use it, you have some options:

- modify your `sys.path`, append path to the repo
- create a symlink under your project directory that points to the repo

And in this way, you don't have to `pip install` every time you modify it.

Comment: I have cloned it to be fair. I wanted to be able to deploy my modified version AND submit relevant changes back as a pull request. I was trying to minimise any extra setup code - I should be able to pick it up from requirements.txt without any extra, but I've spent far too long faffing with it now.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, the best way to do this is to clone the repo. This would go for most packages as pip may build extensions, and carry other actions during install aimed at using the module for production rather than editing the source.

To explain why I chose this structure, I wanted to be able to develop the package inside a Django project. As the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/) say, the app should be placed in a separate directory, which enables setuptools to install the package correctly. There is no way I could find that would enable this to continue to work inside a project, hence the build script to move the files into a suitable directory and generate the package.